# Stretch minipage to align to top and bottom

Tags: xetex, minipage, rules

I'm having two minipages side by side. The left one includes an image and the right one some text. The text is so-called "enclosed" by a rule at the top and the bottom. The text in turn is aligned to the top (below the top rule). Below the text, I want to insert vertical whitespace so that the bottom rule is aligned to the bottom of the image next to it.

Here's a MWE that puts the bottom rule right below the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.jpeg}
\end{minipage}}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.6mm}\\[0.2cm]
    Text
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.6mm}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve the desired effect? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would consider to use a further package, I can provide a `tcolorbox` based solution. If the image is taller than the text, the rules are matched to the image. Otherwise, the rules follow the text:

[image]

The source code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\ImageAndText}[2]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[blankest,sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top seam,
    sidebyside gap=2mm,
    lefthand width=0.4\textwidth,
    before lower=\par\vspace*{2mm},
    after lower=\par\vspace*{2mm},
    underlay={
      \draw[line width=0.6mm] ([yshift=-0.3mm]segmentation.north east)--(interior.north east);
      \draw[line width=0.6mm] ([yshift=0.3mm]segmentation.south east)--(interior.south east);
    },
    ]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}
  \tcblower
  #2
\end{tcolorbox}%
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\ImageAndText{example-image}{Text}

\ImageAndText{example-image}{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can measure the height of the text with `environ` and decide whether it's higher than the figure or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewEnviron{graphicsandtext}[2][]{%
  % #1 (optional)  = the options for \includegraphics
  % #2 (mandatory) = the image file
  \par\noindent
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \raisebox{-\height}{\usebox{0}}%
  \sbox{2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\wd0-\columnsep}
    \hrule depth 0.6mm
    \vspace{2pt}
    \BODY
    \par\vspace{2pt}
    \hrule height 0.6mm
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \ifdim\dp2<\ht0
    \begin{minipage}[t][\ht0][s]{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\wd0-\columnsep}
    \hrule depth 0.6mm
    \vspace{2pt}
    \BODY
    \par
    \vfill
    \vspace{2pt}
    \hrule height 0.6mm
    \end{minipage}
  \else
    \usebox{2}
  \fi
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{graphicsandtext}[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
Some short text
\end{graphicsandtext}

\bigskip

\begin{graphicsandtext}[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\lipsum[3]
\end{graphicsandtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the effect if the second instance has `0.3\textwidth`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case, there are packages for this kind of task (see other answer).  But if you want to achieve this with LaTeX on-board tools, you can use the optional `height` argument from `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
  \quad
  \begin{minipage}[b][4cm][t]{4cm}
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.6mm}\\[0.2cm]
    Text\par
    \vspace{\fill}
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.6mm}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Your Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image]